# Jquery Ajax Always Error is trigerred

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I don't understand why my custom callback error function is always triggered.
If I remove this callback function, my success callback function is triggered.

I read on internet that this a encoding problem but in my case, I don't believe so.

Here my code :

In client

```
myFunction = function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: customUrl,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(buildDatata("custom")),
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: mysuccess,
        error: myerror("Error")
    });
}

buildDatata= function (action) {
    return data = {
        "Action": action,
        "SubscriptionInfo":
        {
            "SiteId": CurrentSiteId,
            "WebId": CurrentWebId,
            "ListId": CurrentListId,
            "ItemId": CurrentItemUniqueId,
            "SubscriptionDate": new Date().toUTCString(),
            "SubscriptionType": GetTypePage()
        }
    }
}
```

In my server :

```
private void HasSubscripted(HttpContext context, BookmarkAction bookmarkAction)
        {

            bool result  = true;

            SendResponse(context,
                new
                {
                    isSubscripted = result
                }
            );

        }

protected void SendResponse(HttpContext context, object jsonResponse)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            context.Response.Write(jsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonResponse));
            context.Response.End();
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are calling a function.... What it returns is being assigned to the event listener

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm dub :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myError("Error")`. Here you are ACTUALLY calling it. You do not need to pass in an argument. `functionName()` actually calls it. Just pass `myError`

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm dub :)

Comment: what does dub mean?

Comment: Missclick, wanted to say "dumb"